# create pdf with custom external fonts in php

Tags: php, tcpdf, wkhtmltopdf, fpdf, html2pdf

I want to create a pdf file with custom fonts so can anybody suggest me 
the best PHP lib except wkhtmltopdf because it not working in shared hosting.

I have tried html2pdf but not able to used with external fonts

Comment: Questions asking to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource **are off-topic for Stack Overflow** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

We can use our desired font in the mpdf(a plugin). But here we need to use inline style for html like, 
style='font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;'

For Mpdf documentation please visit here: https://mpdf.github.io/

Comment: I know this and tried also what I want to implement is third party external fonts like OCR fonts